# getArguments() in Fragment returning null

Tags: android

I've studied all the fragment getArgument null pointer questions already answered and I can't seem to find a solution that works for me.  My fragment is functioning properly (buttons doing proper function) except that it does not get any arguments passed in.  I have set up my constructor and my calls to it various ways, and cannot avoid the NullPoint.  I think it must be something around the lifecycle of the fragment, and the fragment appearing onscreen somehow not being the initiated one, but I can't get to the bottom of it.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Fragment code:

```
public class BottomBar extends Fragment {

ImageButton goHome, goPending, goActive, goHelp, goChallenge;
BottomListener activityCallback;
int chalType;
String title;
String text;

//constructor log.d prints out that it has been reached
public static BottomBar init(int chalType, String ttl, String txt){
    BottomBar bot = new BottomBar();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("chalType", chalType);
    args.putString("title", ttl);
    args.putString("text", txt);
    bot.setArguments(args);
    Log.d("Bottom Bar Init", "called");

    return bot;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
        activityCallback = (BottomListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e){
        Log.d("bottom bar onAttach","class cast");
    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottombarfrag, container, false);
    goHome = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.goHome);
    goPending = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.goPending);
    goChallenge = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.challenge);
    goActive = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.goActive);
    goHelp = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.getInfo);

    Bundle argsin = getArguments();

//never enters this loop... argsin always null
    if(argsin!=null){ 
        Log.d("bottombar oncreate", "argsin found");
    chalType = argsin.getInt("chalType", 0);
    title = argsin.getString("title");
    text = argsin.getString("text");
    }

    //.... button activities, functioning properly ....

    return view;
}
```

and main activity code that calls it:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

Button btn, paydemo;
TextView tv1, tv2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String ttl = "Trial1 Home";
    String txt = "string1text";
    BottomBar bot = BottomBar.init(0, ttl, txt);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, bot).commit();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickbtn);
    paydemo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PayPalDemo);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv1.setText("try1");
    tv2.setText(""); 
    // ...other button actions       
}
```

Follow up:
I've found that I can get the fragment that I want, however it appears as a second instance on the fragment (located on top of display, not where desired), and the original instance is there, but not functioning properly (still with no args).  I think that when I initialize the fragment in my activity I am not overwriting the existing fragment that is added by the xml.  Maybe I need to initialize the Support Fragment Manager and link it to the proper instance to replace it? Thoughts?

xml where originally intended fragment is located (this is the fragment I want, but not the fragment that is being communicated with).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Second Layout"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/retBut"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Return" />


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/bottombar"
    android:name="com.example.trial1.BottomBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"

    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can I see your R.layout.activity_main?

Comment: have you tried using public variables in your BottomBar and directly assign them instead of passing arguments?

Comment: Can you post the code where you activity is getting the fragment manager ?

Comment: @Bend, why you are putting bundle in constructor and you are fetching it onCreateview() ?

Comment: @HirenPatel this is not constructor, this is static initialize method. That's android stuff.

Comment: I have also tried subbing this line:  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, bot).commit();  with .replace() for .add() and not had luck with it

Comment: But what is reason behind that ? Might be you need to pass data from activity to fragement.

Comment: @HirenPatel yes, the need is to pass data. But basically fragment object can be destroyed and collected as garbage at any time when app goes to background. And system uses default constructor to recreate fragment, that's why specific constructors for fragments are not usable. Looks like this is out of scope actually.

Answer (score 0):

This one is tricky. Take a look at your activity: you are setting fragment and after that calling `setContentView`. `setContentView` removes all views from `android.R.id.content`, i think this breaks fragment's lifecycle somehow. Moreover it looks like a concept mistake: setting fragment and wiping it out after that. I suggest making a fragment container inside `R.layout.activity_main`, set activity content and after that put you fragment in this container.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a functioning answer.  I'm not convinced it's the proper way to do it, but it is working.

I created an inherited class for all the classes that reference this fragment, and created a set of public variables to represents the arguments passed to the fragment.  I then had each class write the public variables in the super class instead of initiating a new fragment.  The fragment then referenced the same public variables to pull information from.

Again, don't think it is the proper way to do it - the argument passing exists to be efficient - but it is working for me now.  If anyone has a better idea for how I could accomplish this I'm all ears.

Thanks for all the help